# PHP Regex to get second occurance from the path

Tags: php, regex

I have a path "../uploads/e2c_name_icon/" and I need to extract e2c_name_icon from the path.
What I tried is using str_replace function

```
       $msg = str_replace("../uploads/","","../uploads/e2c_name_icon/");
```

This result in  an output "e2c_name_icon/"

```
       $msg=str_replace("/","","e2c_name_icon/")
```

There is a better way to do this. I am searching alternative method to use regex expression.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Outputs: e2c_name_icon

```
<?php

$path = "../uploads/e2c_name_icon/";

// Outputs: 'e2c_name_icon'
echo explode('/', $path)[2];
```

However, this is technically the third component of the path, the `../` being the first. If you always need to get the third index, then this should work. Otherwise, you'll need to resolve the relative path first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are strictly want to get the last part of the url after '../uploads'

Then you could use this :

```
$url = '../uploads/e2c_name_icon/';
$regex = '/\.\.\/uploads\/(\w+)/';
preg_match($regex, $url, $m)
print_r ($m); // $m[1] would output your url if possible
```

Comment: This seems to be missing at least a line (`preg_match()`?).

Comment: How to use it in regex

Comment: Oh I delete the line, gonna fix it

Answer (score 1):

Use `basename` function provided by PHP.

```
 $var = "../uploads/e2c_name_icon/";
 echo basename( $var ); // prints e2c_name_icon
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trim after the str_replace.

```
echo $msg = trim(str_replace("../uploads/","","../uploads/e2c_name_icon/"), "/");
```

I don't think you need to use regex for this. Simple string functions are usually faster

You could also use strrpos to find the second last `/`, then trim off both `/`.

```
$path = "../uploads/e2c_name_icon/";
echo $msg = trim(substr($path, strrpos($path, "/",-2)),"/");
```

I added -2 in strrpos to skip the last `/`. That means it returns the positon of the `/` after `uploads`.
So substr will return `/e2c_name_icon/` and trim will remove both `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be much better off using the native PHP path functions vs trying to parse it yourself.

For example:

```php
$path = "../uploads/e2c_name_icon/";

$msg = basename(dirname(realpath($path))); // e2c_name_icon
```

Comment: This won't work if `$path` is a virtual path or if `$path` doesn't resolve from the cwd of the script.